# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una posición de un array pasado por los parámetros de la cabecera de mi función?

Tags: java, array, filewriter

Lo que trato de hacer es escribir en un txt distintos tipos de usuarios y para algunos usuarios tengo que pasar un array de varios string que quiero en el txt también. Mi problema viene cuando intento meterlos por separado recorriendo el array con un for pero no puedo acceder a posiciones específicas del array. También en vez de arrayAux[i] he probado con .get(i) y parecidos.Decir también que no he subido todo el código que solo esta parte de una función.

```
    boolean grabado = false;
    List<UsuarioDoctor> usuarios = new ArrayList<UsuarioDoctor>();

    usuarios.add(new UsuarioDoctor(tipo,dni,nombre,apellidos,tlfn,sexo,contrasenia,correo,pacientes));

    String outputFile = "ArchivoDoctorTXT.txt";
    boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();

    if(alreadyExists){
        File ArchivoUsuarios = new File(outputFile);
        ArchivoUsuarios.delete();
    }        
    exportarValidarTxt(tipo,dni,contrasenia);
    try {

        BufferedWriter txtOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true));

        for(UsuarioDoctor user : usuarios){

            txtOutput.write("\"");
            txtOutput.write(user.getTipo()); 
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getDni());
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getNombre());
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getApellidos());
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getTlfn());
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getSexo());
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getContrasenia()); 
            txtOutput.write(",");
            txtOutput.write(user.getCorreo()); 
            txtOutput.write(",");
            //txtOutput.write("\"");
            String[] pacientesAux=user.getPacientes();
            for(int i=0;i<=pacientes.length;i++) {
                txtOutput.write(pacientesAux[i]);//Aquí no funciona
                if(i<pacientes.length) {
                    txtOutput.write(",");
                }
                else if(i==pacientes.length){
                    txtOutput.write("\"");
                }

            }
        }

        txtOutput.close();
        grabado=true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        grabado=false;
    }
    return grabado;
}
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que estas creando la variable pacientesAux en cada iteracion, prueba declarandola antes del  for(UsuarioDoctor user : usuarios) y ya abajo solo le asiganas el valor

Comment: Muchas gracias por la propuesta, pero no funciona. El mismo errorException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at manejoFicheros.ExportarTXT2.exportarDoctorTXT(ExportarTXT2.java:89)
 at main.Main2.main(Main2.java:13)

Comment: for(int i=0;i<=pacientes.length;i++) { --- estas usando pacientes.length y tenes declarado el array en pacientesAux

Comment: Ambos son arrays, pacientes es un array que uso dentro y fuera de la función mientras que pacientesAux nace y muere en la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sacale el `"="` a `pacientes.length`, es un error `IndexOutBounds`, significa que estas buscando en una zona del `array` que no existe.

Por ejemplo, si pacientes tuviese 10, `pacientes.length`, devuelve 10, pero en el `array` se cuenta de 0-9.

espero que sea la solucion, si algo no se entiende, pregunta por favor

Comment: aunque este comentario puede ser la solución, conviene explicar el por que y no solo decir que hacer

Comment: en la zona de comentarios no, por favor dale editar a tu respuesta y añade todo esto que me dices ahi

Comment: se entiende mejor? no estoy seguro si explique bien

Comment: ah y posiblemente tengas que poner en el if del final del for, pacientes.length -1, por lo mismo de arriba no se va a ejecutar nunca si no

Comment: Perfecto, ya se resuelve; no me había dado cuenta que salía de los límites del array. Muchas gracias